# change debugNeedsPaint to false

Tags: dart, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMx3H.png)i created function to take screen shot and append it to empty widget

CODE

```
 Future<Function> TakeScreenShot(BuildContext context) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    print(boundary.debugNeedsPaint);
    //assert(!boundary.debugNeedsPaint);
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    setState(() {
      takenScreenShot.add(Image.memory(
        pngBytes,
        width: 200.0,
        height: 150.0,
      ));
    });
  }
```

but it doesn't run from the first time, the compiler shows

> '!debugNeedsPaint': is not true.

but after the first click it works.
how to change ( debugNeedsPaint ) to false  ?

Comment: Please add the error output as text instead of as screenshot. Screenshots are not searchable.

Comment: E/flutter ( 7249): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7249): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2570 pos 11: '!debugNeedsPaint': is not true.
E/flutter ( 7249): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:37:39)
E/flutter ( 7249): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:33:5)

Comment: E/flutter ( 7249): #2      RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart)
E/flutter ( 7249): #3      _MyHomePageState.takeScreenShot (file:///Users/apple/Desktop/untitled5/lib/main.dart:149:37)
E/flutter ( 7249): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7249): #4      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/apple/Desktop/untitled5/lib/main.dart:100:29)
E/flutter ( 7249): #5      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1125:30)
E/flutter ( 7249): #6      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>